# Where is NESL Microsoft.Silverlight.Windows.dll located?

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to get started with Silverlight Native Extensions and have installed the runtime but I can't find where the Microsoft.Silverlight.Windows.dll assembly is to reference it. I've recursively searched my Program Files/(x86) directories with PoSh to no avail. Anybody know?

Comment: someone suggested looking under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight but they are definitely not under there. I checked sub-folders as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the  NESLSourceV2.zip file from http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nesl/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5519

it contains the Microsoft.Silverlight.Windows project in SilverlightLibraries folder.

Comment: It seems very odd that Microsoft would require us to download and compile the source in order to use these tools. Seems very Linuxy :) Especially for a v2 release.